# F# context.DataContext.ExecuteStoreQuery

Tags: f#, fsharp.data.sqlclient

Has anyone used context.DataContext.ExecuteStoreQuery?  I am using the SqlEntityConnection to pull data from a stored procedure defined as such

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CustOrderHist] @CustomerID nchar(5)
AS
SELECT ProductName, Total=SUM(Quantity)
FROM Products P, [Order Details] OD, Orders O, Customers C
WHERE C.CustomerID = @CustomerID
AND C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID AND O.OrderID = OD.OrderID AND OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
GROUP BY ProductName
```

With this F# code

```
let RunCustomerStoredProcedure () =
    let context = schema.GetDataContext()
    let query = context.DataContext.ExecuteStoreQuery("CustOrderHist",new SqlParameter("CustomerID","AFKLI"))
    query |> Seq.iter(fun (pn,t) -> Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}",pn,t)))
```

but I am getting this exception:

> `Procedure or function 'CustOrderHist' expects parameter '@CustomerID', which was not supplied.`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
let RunCustomerStoredProcedure () =
    let context = schema.GetDataContext()
    let query =
        context.DataContext.ExecuteStoreQuery(
            "CustOrderHist",
            new SqlParameter("@CustomerID","AFKLI"))
    query |> Seq.iter(fun (pn,t) -> Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}",pn,t)))
```

Notice the additional `@` in `"@CustomerID"`.

Comment: I did try that even though the docs said to drop the '@'.  Still no luck.